# Inserting user tweets into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter

I am getting user tweets and mentions and inserting into table. Once this process completes, I redirect to next page.

For few users it correctly stores and display tweets and redirect to next page. But for few user, it stuck on the first page where I get tweets and store into table. I am trying since last few days to overcome this.

Can any one tell me what problem can cause this? Does it is due to it unable to store the data (tweet text) into table?

There are two function in which I perform insert operation:

```
        function lookup($tweetid,$connection,$userid)
        {
                $tweets5 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/".$tweetid.".json?count=1");
                //var_dump($tweets5);
                $json = json_encode($tweets5);
                foreach($tweets5 as $item)
                {
                        $text = $item->text;
            $text_id = $item->id;
//                        $user_id = $item->user->id;
                        $name = $item->user->name;
            $constant = 'retweet';
            $time = $item->created_at;
            $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s e Y', $time);
//          $dt = new \DateTime($time);
            $tweet_time = $dt->format('H:m:s');
            $tweet_dtm = $dt->format('Y:m:d');
            $year =  $dt->format('Y'); 
            $month =  $dt->format('m'); 

            echo $text."-".$text_id."-".$name."-".$time."-".$tweet_time.$tweet_dtm.$year.$month.$rt_count.$follower.$friend."<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            $inreplyto =  $item->in_reply_to_screen_name;

                     $follower = $item->user->followers_count;
            $rt_count = $item->retweet_count;
                        $friend = $item->user->friends_count;
                    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'karim', 'karim');

            $text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);

                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                            return;
                    }

                    $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO twitter_retweet(`username`,`userid`,`tweet_text`,`text_id`,`time`,`month`,`year`,`date`,`user_follower_count`,`rt_count`,`constant`,`in_reply_to`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$userid."','".$text."','".$text_id."','".$tweet_time."','".$month."','".$year."','".$tweet_dtm."','".$follower."','".$rt_count."','".$constant."','".$inreplyto."')";

                    if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
                    {
                          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                    //      echo "error";
                    }

//                        echo  "Text : $text <br>  ID : $user_id <br> Name : $name <br> Follower : $follower <br> Friends : $friend <br> ---";
                }


        }
```

Is there anything wrong in this code? I am not sure whether it stuck here during insertion or what.

2nd function, this prints the data, but it does not store `$text` into database. why?:

```
    foreach ($tweets1 as $item)
    {
        $text = $item->text;
        //echo $userid.$text;
        $text_id = $item->id;
        $constant = 'mention';
        $time = $item->created_at;
        //echo $time;
        //$dt = new DateTime('@' . strtotime($time));
        $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s e Y', $time);
        //var_dump($dt);
        $tweet_time = $dt->format('H:m:s');
        $tweet_dtm = $dt->format('Y:m:d');
        $year =  $dt->format('Y'); 
        $month =  $dt->format('m'); 
        $user_name = $item->user->name;
//      echo $year.$month.$user_name;
        $inreplyto =  $item->in_reply_to_screen_name;
        $rt_count = $item->retweet_count;
        $follower_count = $item->user->followers_count;


        echo $text."-".$text_id."-".$time."-".$tweet_time.$tweet_dtm.$year.$month.$user_name.$rt_count.$follower_count."<br>";
        echo "<br>";

        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'karim', 'karim');           
        //$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($text);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            return;
        }

        $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO twitter_mention(`username`,`userid`,`tweet_text`,`text_id`,`time`,`month`,`year`,`date`,`user_follower_count`,`rt_count`,`constant`,`in_reply_to`) VALUES ('".$twitteruser."','".$userid."','".$text."','".$text_id."','".$tweet_time."','".$month."','".$year."','".$tweet_dtm."','".$follower_count."','".$rt_count."','".$constant."','".$inreplyto."')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        //  echo "error";
        }       
    }
```

This is the code at the end to redirect to next page:

```
echo '<form name="myForm" id="myForm"  action="start.php" method="POST">
<input style="display:none" name="userid" value="'.$userid.'" />

</form>

<script>
    function submitform()
    {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
    window.onload = submitform;
</script>
';
```

Comment: Maybe some tweets have ` in them.

Comment: @Mihai: I doubt, what is the solution for this? any other possible issue in storing the data into mysql?

Comment: IN general you should use prepared statements http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: Also you are using mysqli to connect and using mysql_escape.. use mysqli_escape.If I`m not mistaken escape funtion needs its connection to work,so it might be that mysql_escape with mysqli conecction doesnt do anything.

Comment: @Mihai: I corrected it, but still issue persist. `Text` does not getting stored in 2nd function

Comment: I removed `mysqli_real_escape_string($text);` from 2nd function, now it stores data into table. But still stuck on same page, but does not redirect to next page

Comment: Maybe you need to set the charset http://ro1.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Reverse the order of quotes here `"'.$userid.'"` and use the call to function with () `submitform();`

Comment: @Mihai: Does it really make difference? Actually page works fine for most of the user, for few users only(may be due to their data) it fails

Comment: Reversing the order creates problem for all case. Checked